# admin is not able to approve post for the required like field django

Tags: django

In my django project, users can create posts. but the admin has to approve the post first. Then the users can see the posts created by them in their timeline. The users can like or unlike post from the post-detail page. However, when the admin logs in from the django admin panel to approve post and click the save button, it shows that the 'like' field is required. How can I solve this problem so that the admin can approve the post?

blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField # first I installed ckeditor by this command: pip install django-ckeditor

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    cid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name


class Post(models.Model):
    aid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='blog-default.png', upload_to='images/')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # content = models.TextField()
    content = RichTextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cid = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='specialization')
    approved = models.BooleanField('Approved', default=False)
    like = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), related_name='likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


    @property
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.like.count()
```

users/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from blog.models import Category
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser 

# Create your models here.
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    cid = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='default_person.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
```

blog/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Comment

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'image', 'cid']

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'image': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'cid': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }


class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'image', 'cid']

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'cid': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

users/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model # I changed the default User model. So I need to change the way I access it The right way to use it is get_user_model()
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm # it is used to create a new user
from blog.models import Category

User = get_user_model()

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['specialization'].required = True

    email = forms.EmailField()

    categories = Category.objects.all()
    specialization = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=categories)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'specialization']
```

blog/post-detail.html

```
{% extends 'users/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ object.title }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ object.content|safe }}</p>
            <p class="card-text"> <b> Specialization: </b> {{ object.cid }} </p>
            {% if object.author == user %} 
            <div>
                <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.aid %}">Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.aid %}">Delete</a>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            <hr>
            <form action="{% url 'post-like' object.pk %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% if post_is_liked %}
                <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{object.aid}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Unlike</button>
                {% else %}
                <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{object.aid}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Like</button>
                {% endif %}
                - {{ post.like.count }} Likes
              </form>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-secondary">
            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'other-people-profile' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>|| 
            {{ object.created|date:"F d, Y" }}
        </div> 
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

[image: ADMIN UI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field like is not mark as optional.

```py
like = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), related_name='likes', blank=True)
```